# only sound is being generated not video Why?

Tags: android

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    try {

        mp.setDisplay(holder);
        mp.setDataSource("/sdcard/family.3gp");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Surface created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Surface created 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e1.printStackTrace();
```

Her i'm only getting the sound and i'm unable to get the video .... Please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using the emulator. The emulator will not have good enough performance to play back most videos. Please test video applications using an Android device.

Also, never hardwire `/sdcard`, as it is wrong for most Android devices. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the root of external storage.